# Jquery replace multiple string in element, not replace element

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Hello good friends :)

I have a question about jquery. Is there a function in jquery to replace the many words that have been mapped within an object or array.

Example in php:

```
<?php 
    $textBefore  = "PHP is amazing open source programmer language, 
                    there many webs around the world that are built using php";
    $forReplace  = array("amazing","programmer","webs");
    $replacement = array("powerfull","programming","websites");
    $textAfter   = str_replace( $forReplace , $replacement , $textBefore);
    echo $textAfter;
?>
```

it will be produce

```
PHP is powerfull open source programming language, 
there many websites around the world that are built using php
```

How do I do a similar thing in jquery?
I did this to reduce the performance of the server so I thought to do this work by the browser. Because the contents fr replace in one show page is too much.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need jQuery, just use Javascript's replace method.

```
var text  = 'PHP is amazing open source programmer language, there many webs around the world that are built using php';

text = text.replace('amazing', 'powerful');
text = text.replace('programmer', 'programming');
text = text.replace('webs', 'websites');
```

You can replicate PHP's str_replace method like so:

```
function str_replace(search, replace, subject) {
    for (i=0; i<replace.length; i++) {
        subject = subject.replace(search[i], replace[i]);
    }
    return subject;
}

var subject = "This is a test string.";
var search = ['test', 'string'];
var replace = ['cool', 'thang'];

subject = str_replace(search, replace, subject);

\\ subject is now 'This is a cool thang';
```

Comment: I already know that but what I need is a function to simultaneously run all of the turn. Does that mean I have to do it over and over again without mapping the object? Is this the last?

Comment: I added code to show you how to replicate PHP's str_replace method.

Answer (score 2):

```
var value = $("#text").val(); // value = 9.61 use $("#text").text() if you are not on select box...
value = value.replace(".", ":"); // value = 9:61
// can then use it as
$("#anothertext").val(value);
```

Comment: these isn't an array though, you could probably fix it with jquery.each()

Comment: I already know that but what I need is a function to simultaneously run all of the turn. Does that mean I have to do it over and over again without mapping the object? Is this the last?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with one for cycle.

```
var text = "This is some sample text.";
var target = ['some', 'text'];
var replace = ['replaced', 'sentence'];

for(var i = 0; i < replace.length; i++){
    text = text.replace(target[i], replace[i])
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/az39r3hp/)

Answer (score 1):

Refer [phpjs.org](http://phpjs.org) which has javascript implementations of php functions.

The code for str_replace is given below. Source : http://phpjs.org/functions/str_replace/

```
function str_replace(search, replace, subject, count) {
  var i = 0,
    j = 0,
    temp = '',
    repl = '',
    sl = 0,
    fl = 0,
    f = [].concat(search),
    r = [].concat(replace),
    s = subject,
    ra = Object.prototype.toString.call(r) === '[object Array]',
    sa = Object.prototype.toString.call(s) === '[object Array]';
  s = [].concat(s);
  if (count) {
   this.window[count] = 0;
  }

  for (i = 0, sl = s.length; i < sl; i++) {
    if (s[i] === '') {
      continue;
    }
    for (j = 0, fl = f.length; j < fl; j++) {
      temp = s[i] + '';
      repl = ra ? (r[j] !== undefined ? r[j] : '') : r[0];
      s[i] = (temp)
    .split(f[j])
    .join(repl);
      if (count && s[i] !== temp) {
        this.window[count] += (temp.length - s[i].length) / f[j].length;
      }
    }
  }
  return sa ? s : s[0];
}
```

Usage:

```
$textBefore  = "PHP is amazing open source programmer language,there many webs around the world that are built using php";
$forReplace  = ["amazing","programmer","webs"];
$replacement = ["powerfull","programming","websites"];
$textAfter   = str_replace( $forReplace , $replacement , $textBefore);
```

`$textAfter` will have `PHP is powerfull open source programming language,there many websites around the world that are built using php`

Comment: Please try to avoid link only answers rather add relevant code.

Comment: @hinata: had some issues with formatting while i was copying and pasting the code. so just gave the link. Will keep this in mind from now on.